# How do I find the RGB values of part specific portion of an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

So say I find the coordinates of the square and the coordinates of the letter in the linked image using haarcascade. How do I find the rgb value of the square only using OpenCV? I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, but I'd like to know how to do this.

[image: Here's an example of the image]

Note that the grass would actually take a majority of the image when i'm actually using this program.

Thank's in advance!!

Comment: Thanks of the edit Wilf. I'm not allowed to post images myself yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a pixel in a CV_8UC3 (that is a 3 channel image with unsigned char data type), you can write:

```
const Vec3u& pixel = image.at<Vec3u>(row, col);
```

As you say you have the coordinates of the box and the letter, you just need to put them here.

**Update**: If the areas are not of a single color and you need to get an average, you can go this way:

1. Create a mask `m1` that covers all the pixels of the letter with `cv::fillPoly`.
2. Use `cv::mean` with the image and the mask `m1` to get the average color of your letter.
3. Create a mask `m2` that covers all the pixels of your box, again with `cv::fillPoly`.
4. Since this mask will contain the pixels of the letter as well, you have to "remove" `m1` from `m2`. Do it with `cv::setTo`.
5. Use `cv::mean` again with the image and the mask `m2` to get the average color of your box.

Comment: okay, so using a loop, I can just add up all the values and average them to to find the color of the region of interest. Thanks a ton!! I you give you vote up, but I need 15 rep to do so :/ .

Comment: Well, in your image, all the areas seem to be of a single color, no? In that case you only need one pixel.

Comment: well in an actual test, the image wouldn't be as perfect as it is in this example. That one pixel could be on an abnormally dark spot, or just barely off the border of the red part.